# How do I update the current keyPressed in a KeyEvent for java?

Tags: java, keyevent

I would be extremely grateful if some one could help me with my code, I'm learning code as I develop games.

- I'm trying to make the controls on a basic PONG game feel smooth, but I have this problem with the keyEvent/keyPressed. I am using A to go left, D to go right, when I hold D then press A, without letting go of D it will notice the change and go left, but once i let go of A with D still held down, the keyEvent will not notice that D is held down, which makes the racquet not move until you press D again.
  **Is there a way to tell the keyEvent or keyPressed to update on whats happening at the moment and react to it?**

Here's the fragment of the code...
p.s. I'm new to stack overflow and not a fluent java programmer I'm still learning. I'm sorry if my question is very vague or unspecific... 
also, move(1) makes coordinates of the racquet move x+=1 and move(-1) x-=1*/

> Fix attempt#1 :
>    I tried using a return statement after a change was made hoping that would work, no result...

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    //MOVE LEFT
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){               
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            move(1);
            //maybe update?
            return;
        }                           
        else
            move(-1);           
    }       
    //MOVE RIGHT
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){                   
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            move(-1);
            //maybe update?
            return;
        }
        else
            move(1);
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this situation is to create a boolean array and store the values of everything in there and then use it later. This allows for updates to be handled a bit more smoothly and allows for you to have a bit more of organization. To create the array at the top type

```
public static boolean[] keys = new boolean[999];
```

Then in the press method do

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
}
```

And finally in the release method

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
}
```

Then to reference it later simply use

```
[class].keys[KeyEvent.[key]]
```

Comment: @orangeSauce My bad I got this code by copying and pasting it from code I already written. It's removed now